! Package pgf Error: No shape named `current page text area' is known
I've just updated to TL 2024 on Linux manjaro.
When compiling an existing document without making any changes, it was failing. After much debugging, I found it is in tikz code I had. Here is MWE
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(current page text area.south west)},scale=0.75,transform shape]    
    \coordinate (O) at  (8,22);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Now
 lualatex --shell-escape  A.tex

gives
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024) 
 system commands enabled.
(./A.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
....
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

! Package pgf Error: No shape named `current page text area' is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.14 ...rea.south west)},scale=0.75,transform shape]
                                                  
? 

If the above code is wrong, how did it use to compile OK in TL 2023? I am sure I compiled this before many times as the file is few years old and do clean build all the time and I have not seen such an error before.  So something seems to have changed.
How to correct the above so it compiles OK?
The file I found this in is very large, but the log file shows the same error there also.

Those nodes are not defined by default. Probably you want
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

If you were not loading it before, perhaps another package loaded it but no longer does.

Thanks. This fixed it.  I used same preamble I had in my large file. So it looks then like you said that these nodes where defined in TL 2023 somewhere else.

@Nasser given the changes to shipout, this could easily have changed if a package opted for the kernel hooks e.g. the result would likely be much more efficient. I am not sure there is that much need for these nodes, though they may be convenient for older code. (& maybe there are more interesting uses of them I'm not aware of.)
